# Repeat elements of list python

Tags: python

I have a list of floats and want to multiply each value by a number. Code will explain it better:

```
list = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
```

and now I want to do an operation so that:

```
list =[1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,3.0]
```

so for example multiply each value by 3 in the way shown.
Unfortunately I don't have a clue how to do that.

Comment: You want to *repeat* each value, not *multiply* it (which would give `[3.0, 6.0, 9.0]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lst = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
>>> [x for x in lst for i in range(3)]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in list:
    for i in xrange(0,2):
        list.append(l)
```